# can you modify the filename during "find"

Tags: find

`find` uses `{}` to indicate "this file"(ish). You can feed a series of files into `myprog`, thus:

```
find ./tests/ -name *.in -exec myprog -i {} \;
```

Is there a way to modify the name in `{}`? In my case, I use `-i` to define an input file and `-o` for the output, and I would like the output to go to a slightly modified file name, such that "a.in" would produce "a.out". Ideally, I would like something to the effect of:

```
find ./tests/ -name *.in -exec myprog -i {} -o {}.out \;
```

Additionally, the output directory may be a different path. In this case, the output would not go to `/tests/` but perhaps `/tests_20220615/`.

I've looked at numerous pages with examples of `find`, and nothing like this shows up, so perhaps "no"?

I know there are ways to do this using loops in bash or zsh, but the list of possible gotchas is great ("nullglob"?!), and if `find` can do this it seems much safer to this noob.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`find` won't let you modify the paths of the files, some `find` implementations would not let you concatenate `{}` with something else, some don't even support passing `{}` more than once, but you can always run some command such as a shell that can do transformations:

```
find ./tests/ -name '*.in' -type f -exec sh -c '
  ret=0
  for file do
    myprog -i "$file" -o "${file%.*}.out" || ret="$?"
  done
  exit "$ret"' sh {} +
```

Above, instead of executing `myprog` directly, we're executing `sh` and passing it some inline code as well as the paths of the found file (with `{} +` instead of `{} ';'` to pass as many as possible).

`sh` in turn loops over those files, and calls `myprog` after having applied transformations on them like `${file%.*}` to remove the extension.

Note the quotes around `*.in`. Without them the shell you're running that `find` command in would try to expand it to the list of files in the current directory whose name ends in `.in` instead of passing that pattern literally to `find`.

Above, we tell `sh` to exit with a failure exit status if any of the `myprog` invocations fails. That failure will be reflected in the exit status of `find`, so you can take action if need be or the script to exit if the `errexit` option is enabled. It's not possible to abort upon the first failure of `myprog` though.

If using the `zsh` shell, you could also do the finding internally:

```
set -o errexit
for file (./tests/**/*.in(ND.)) myprog -i $file -o $file:r.out
```

Would exit upon the first failure and would also process the list in lexical order (you can always add the `oN` glob qualifier to disable that sorting).

Another approach is to get `find` to print the files, pipe it to some command that does the transformations and then pipe to `xargs`. For instance:

```
find ./tests/ -name '*.in' -type f -print0 |
  gawk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' -v OFS='\0' '
    {
      filein = fileout = $0; sub(/\.in$/, ".out", fileout)
      print "-i", filein, "-o", fileout
    }' | xargs -r0 -n4 myprog
```

Again `xargs` will return with a non-zero exit status if any of the `myprog` invocations fails. GNU `xargs` can run several invocations in parallel with its `-P` option.

Or you could get `perl` to post-process it and let it do the running:

```
find ./tests/ -name '*.in' -type f -print0 |
  perl -l -0ne '
    system("myprog", "-i", $_, "-o", s/\.in\Z/.out/r) == 0 or
      $ret = 1;
    END {exit $ret}'
```

Beware that the approaches that post-process the output of `find` will mask its failure exit status if any (like when it fails to enter some directories) unless you set the `pipefail` of your shell (where supported).

Using pipes also have an implication on what `myprog`'s standard input will be (in case it needs to prompt the user for instance). GNU `xargs` opens stdin on `/dev/null`, some others and the `perl` approach will leave it as is which means it will be the pipe from `find`/`gawk`.

Comment: Will I need to worry about quoting and nullglob and such in this case?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz, you always need to worry about quoting :-), once you fix the missing quotes around `*.in`, there's no globbing involved any longer so `nullglob` cannot have any effect.

Comment: I was curious about the seeming simplicity of the zsh solution so I did a bit of poking about. Wow, those :t's and such are *extremely* handy! I think this is the solution I'll go with. Thanks for the detailed answers!

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz, note that the `:r`, `:t`... are not specific to zsh, they're from csh in the late 70s.  Also supported by `vim`. Also by `bash` but only for history expansion (a feature it also borrowed from csh). zsh did add quite a few of those modifiers and improved some of them.

Answer (score 1):

You have already received a very good answer. However, I think the premise of your question is not what it should be. You shouldn't be fearful of writing loops in bash and given the fact that you still need to be careful using other utilities, then I don't see any reason not to use bash in this case.

In this example, there is nothing wrong with simply doing this:

```
for file in test/*; do 
    [[ -e "$file" ]] || continue
    echo cp "$file" "${file/test/tests_20220615}.out"; 
done
```

```
cp test/1.in test_20220615/1.out
cp test/10.in test_20220615/10.out
cp test/2.in test_20220615/2.out
cp test/3.in test_20220615/3.out
cp test/4.in test_20220615/4.out
cp test/5.in test_20220615/5.out
...
```

This will work regardless of the default `nullglob` behavior. In particular, add a condition to check for files (`[[ -e "$i" ]]`, true if a file with that name exists) and if you're unsure about the output, throw an echo statement there (or even better `printf`) and make sure everything looks right.

Comment: Note that this won't go into subdirectories like `find` does, but maybe that's not needed. The wildcard should be `test/*.in`. Where is `1212` coming from, shouldn't that be `_20220615`? And where do you remove `.in`?

Comment: Fixed. I used a simpler directory name to simulate OP's requirements. You can enable globstar to use recursive globs instead.